# toggling element with javascript is making the element appear too small until I resize the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

**edit**

Since originally posting this question, I've gone down a couple more paths trying to solve the issue. It's still not solved, but now my questions are different. The original question is below, and then I'll add a section below that with updates.

**original question**

I'm working on a Rails 4 application and having some trouble with JavaScript and the Chartkick gem.

I have two JavaScript functions that make it so that a user can click an icon and an element will drop down below the icon/appear on the page, and the icon will switch from a right-pointing arrow to a down-pointing arrow. The code is this:

```
function ReverseDisplay(d)
{
  if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none")
  {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('.toggle-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-arrow-circle-o-down');
  });
});
```

And the haml:

```
%a{href: "javascript:ReverseDisplay('toggle-stats#{item.id}')", class: 'toggle-icon'}
  %i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-o-right
%div{id: "toggle-stats#{item.id}", style: "display: none;"}

  = the items to be displayed
```

It works. However, I expect the items that drop down to take up the full width of the page, like so:

[image]

But instead, when I first click the toggle icon, they show up squished, like this:

[image]

If I then resize the browser just a tiny bit, the graph pops out to full-width, and it stays that way no matter what I do from there. I can't figure out how to get ahold of the generated mark-up, because this chart comes from Chartkick, as a gem. The generated html in the browser has this line:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
```

Where the `width: 300px` is what's being changed to `width: 1000px` when I change the browser size. I don't have to change the browser size permanently or significantly. Once that width has changed to 1000px the first time it stays there - but the minute I refresh the page and click the icon to toggle the chart again, it's back to 300px. I don't know how to hook into this div, because it's generated by the gem and I don't know how to add a class to it. I've tried adding styling to a parent element that ensures all of that parent elements' children are `width: 100%`, but that doesn't do anything.

Anyway, I don't think that adding a class to it is the solution here. I just have no idea what is - I don't JavaScript incredibly well. I'm pretty much completely new to all front-end work as a whole. What's going on here, and how can I make these charts always be the full width of the page when they're toggled?

Notes: Am testing this in Chrome. I tested in Firefox and it does the same thing.

---

OK, I'm starting to wonder if this has something to do with the fact that I'm using a JavaScript function in order to capture dynamic item IDs - a page may have any number of these toggle-able charts, and so calling a jQuery function on each id seems impossible, because I don't know what ID is.

I removed the jQuery call, however, and the problem persists.

One of those times when rubber-ducking the Stack Overflow question box has not yet answered my question. So I guess I'll submit and hope for outside help here. :/

**adjusted question**

[This](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/28) question in the Github issues for Chartkick has lead me down a different path. The solution is not necessarily in attempting to restyle the charts at all. Instead, what I'm trying to do is trigger a resize event, because the chart automatically regenerates when the browser window is resized. This is both what's causing the problem and where the solution seems to lie.

My code:

```
.row
  .col-sm-12
    %h3.title-block.second-child
      Stats by Video
    .panel-groupd#faqList
      - @claim.presenter.videos.each_with_index do |video, index|
        .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading
            %h4.panel-title
              %a.chart{data: { toggle: "collapse", parent: "#faqList" }, href: "#video#{index}" }
                = "'#{video.title}' at #{video.event.display_name} on #{display_date(video.recorded_at)}"
           %div.panel-collapse.collapse{id: "#video#{index}"}
             .panel-body
               - if video.impressions.count > 0
                 %h4
                   Impressions by Hours (24 hours)
                 = line_chart video.impressions.group_by_day(:created_at, range: 1.day.ago...Time.now).count
                 ...a couple more charts
:javascript
  $(".chart").click(function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  });
```

So the intention here is that when I click the `.panel-heading`, this both drops down the `.panel-body` with the charts in it and resizes the window, which makes the charts resize correctly (or, rather, *should*).

It kind of works, in that, when I first click the `.panel-heading` trigger, it does not resize the charts, but when I click it *again*, the charts are resized perfectly for a split second... just before they become hidden from view again. :(

I've tried adding a time out to the javascript, like so:

```
:javascript
  $(".chart").click(function() {
    setTimeout(1000);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  });
```

But it doesn't appear to do anything at all.

So what I'm wondering here is how to get this `resize` event to work once the dropdown `.panel-body` is out so that the charts will resize appropriately on their own.

Here's a screen cast of the current problem, in case I didn't describe it clearly enough:

[https://youtu.be/5quMGABoDs8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5quMGABoDs8&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Ruby or Chartkick, but in order to override that inline styling, you would have to use `!important`in the css.

So, if you try that technique of giving all the children of the parent element `width: 100%` again, you might want to implement it something like this:

```
.importantRule { width: 100% !important; } 
$( "parentElement > childElement" ).addClass('importantRule');
```

(First line goes in your CSS file, second line goes in JS)

Comment: Thank you for your input - sorry it took so long to reply! However, this was not the right path. :( I'm updating my original question now, as I've tried quite a few more things and kind of figured out the right direction but still not the implementation as of yet.